# На бирже труда - стоят? состоят? состоят на учёте?

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-слов, выбор-варианта

> Но работы немного в таких городках, поэтому он состоит на бирже труда
>   и, как только работа будет, он тотчас вернётся в Германию.

И запятая перед "и" - ставить? не ставить?

Comment: Обосновать можно и постановку, и непостановку запятой. Лучше не ставить. И убрать второе "он".

Comment: Слава, спасибо! Вы мой утешитель! )))

Comment: состоит -> числится; будет -> появится

Comment: Саш, не ёрничай - отвечай! Мне главное - можно ль оставить как есть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Мнения по этому вопросу неоднозначны, поэтому приходится выбирать.

Из словаря Кузнецова: **Стать** на учет (на бирже труда). **Состоять** на учете на бирже труда.

Если в разговорном варианте убрать ***учет,***  то лучше выбрать ***стоять на бирже,*** так как ***стоять*** может иметь самостоятельное значение  СТОЯТЬ 8.  Занять какое-л. положение, позицию по отношению к кому-, чему-л.

Обсуждение вопроса на форуме Грамоты.ру http://gramota.ru/forum/spravka/120731

2) Но работы немного в таких городках, поэтому он **стоит на бирже** труда **и**, как только работа будет,  тотчас **вернётся** в Германию.

Второе местоимение ***он*** убираем. Получается БСП, однородные сказуемые ***стоит и вернется,*** запятой перед И нет.

Answer (score 1):

В словаре Ушакова:
[стоять](https://slovar.cc/rus/ushakov/456804.html)
5. В предложных сочетаниях с существительными, в сочетаниях с прилагательными и качественными наречиями употребляется как вспомогательный глагол, в значении быть каким-нибудь, быть в каком-нибудь состоянии, положении, обладать каким-нибудь свойством, быть занятым каким-нибудь делом – в соответствии со значением сущ., прил. или нареч.
Стоять у власти. Стоять во главе. Стоять на страже чего-нибудь. Стоять за рулем.

*По словам Константина Михайловича Иванова, ректора БГТУ «Военмех», ни один выпускник вуза никогда **не стоял на бирже труда*** (из статьи).

Думаю, что предложение "Но работы немного в таких городках" можно считать общим для двух последующих, поэтому запятая перед **и** не требуется. Я бы написала так:
*Но работы немного в таких городках, поэтому он **стоит на бирже труда** и, как только работа будет, тотчас вернётся в Германию.*